# What should I check when buying a used domain in order to reduce the risk of buying domain with a bad history

Tags: seo, domains, purchase

I am about to purchase a .com domain directly from its owner.

- Domain is 20yrs old.
- Domain is not used for anything in particular, just a few ads on it.
- Not able to track backlinks as looks like robots.txt blocks crawling.
- Domain is not on an email blacklist.

What else should I check, ask the owner about in order to reduce the risk of buying domain with a bad history, SEO etc?

Answer (score 4):

Content: You could use the Internet Archive to see whether they have screen shots of what the site has shown in the past.

Backlinks: You can do a `site:` search on Google and Bing to see what they list as backlinks.

Other info: If you have access to a tool like Moz Pro, you can check on things like spam score, inbound links, and domain authority. You can also run a free analysis on Alexa.com to see what kind of keywords the site has been ranking for, how much traffic it gets, and where the audience is from.